# Using the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort class

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, serial-port

So I've heard a bit about hos the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort is broken or wrongly implemented.
Some events never fire and you should not use it/part of it.
I read the article on:
https://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport#comment-9986

But this article and everything I can find on this topic is a couple of years back and a couple of .NET Framework versions back.

Does anyone know if it is safe to use this class already and whether it functions as it should?

Comment: You can be sure that little has changed. I would follow the advice from that article.

Comment: Starting from Jan 31, 2017 this namespace is ported to .NET Core, https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.IO.Ports You can report issues directly to the GitHub repo.